# Save dataframe in Shiny to access it later and download it?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm new to shiny. 
I have a very basic question but I can't find a solution here on stackoverflow.
I am using directory Input function created by wleepang (https://github.com/wleepang/shiny-directory-input).
I wrote a function `read_files` that **rbind** all files in the directory selected. 
I can display this table with **renderTable**, this works perfectly. But I do not manage to save this table to work with later (check for missing data, add columns, draw ggplots..) and to download is with **write.xlsx**

```
ui <- fluidPage(
directoryInput('directory', label = 'select a directory'),
actionButton("upload", label="Hochladen"),
downloadButton("download", label="Runterladen")
)  

server <- function(input, output, session) {
#this part is to set the directory
 observeEvent(
 ignoreNULL = TRUE,
 eventExpr = {
   input$directory
 },
 handlerExpr = {
   if (input$directory > 0) {
  path = choose.dir(default = readDirectoryInput(session, 'directory'))
  updateDirectoryInput(session, 'directory', value = path)
  }})
#now comes the actual code

  observeEvent(input$upload,{
 df <- read_files(readDirectoryInput(session, 'directory'))
})
```

How can I access this df later?

```
output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
   filename = function() { 
     paste('tabelle', '.csv', sep="") },
   content = function(file) {
     write.xlsx(df, file)
   }
 )
}
```

And my second question how can I download it as a xlsx file in the set directory?

my global.r with the `read_files` function

```
source('directoryInput.R')
read_files = function(inDir, pat="*.csv", readMe=read.csv2){
files = list.files(inDir, pattern=pat)
files = lapply(files, function(x) file.path(inDir, x))
df = do.call(rbind, lapply(files, readMe))
return(df)
}
```

Comment: _1._ you can save your data using [`save`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/save.html) as `R object` and then read it using [`load`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.0/topics/load), _2._ To download as xlxs look into [this](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/xlsx/versions/0.5.7/topics/write.xlsx)

Comment: @parth I have saved the element using a reactive function `upload_data <- eventReactive(input$upload, {
     read_files(readDirectoryInput(session, 'directory'))
    
   })`
and can access it through 
`upload_data()`
this works for me

Comment: @parth save doesn't work in shiny or can you give me a code example? thx

Answer (score 0):

I have saved the element using a reactive function

```
upload_data <- eventReactive(input$upload, {      
read_files(readDirectoryInput(session, 'directory')) })
```

and can access it through `upload_data()` this works for me